# Parse Advanced Targeting not sending push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, notifications

I'm using advanced targeting with parse. On the Parse dashboard it shows that the notification was sent successfully, but it doesn't show to whom when I click on the notification in the dashboard. I have also set up my PFInstallation correctly in App Delegate. Here is my code to send the notification:

```
    let message = "\(PFUser.currentUser()?.username) has invited you to a match!"
    let username = defender

    let query = PFInstallation.query()!
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: username)

    let push = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(query)
    push.setMessage(message)

    push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && success{
            print("push notification sent to user \(defender)!")
        }
    }
```

Username is the target username. The dashboard shows the username as a key. These are the push notification's details:

Push Details

PUSH ID
hOX5Ulhcds

TARGETING
username is ""

SENDING TIME
December 21st, 2015 at 2:02 PM

EXPIRATION
None

FULL TARGET
{ 
  "username": "" 
}

FULL DATA
{ 
  "alert": "Optional(\"John Cena\") has invited you to a match!" 
}

This is the code I run when the user logs in or signs up:

```
let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
currentInstallation["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
```

How do I make my code work?

Comment: Does installation have an attribute called username?

Comment: @danh yes it does. It is a string.